# Object binding for RESTful service using apache-cxf

Tags: rest, binding, cxf

How to bind an object for RESTful service using Apache CXF?
I want to bind variables to an object from url params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `@QueryParam`. Take a look  [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-DealingwithParameters)